# how to set full screen layout for all activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

i want make to become full screen, and adaptable for all smartphone, this code part that creates a tablelayout scrollable both horizontally and vertically, also i want to view the matrix of edittext centered on the layout. Thanks

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.seconda);

    HorizontalScrollView HSC = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
    ScrollView VSC = new ScrollView(this);
    VSC.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna_psd);

    tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 

    values = new EditText[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      tableRow = new TableRow(this); 
      tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

      for (int j = 0; j < 3  ; j++) {
        values[i][j] = new EditText(this);
        values[i][j].setHint("r: " + (i) + " " + "c: " + (j));
        values[i][j].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tableRow.addView(values[i][j]);
      }

      tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }

    VSC.addView(tableLayout);
    HSC.addView(VSC);
    setContentView(HSC);

}
```

Comment: set android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" for activity in manifest,please check it is work?

Comment: i edited my question for better explain my problem. However, this part of the code refers to a second activity of my app, and in this activity there is an image as background

Comment: Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

You can make your application full screen either in xml configuration or in Java code. Below you can find how to do this in both cases.

Create your own customized style in styles.xml located in directory res/values. You can turn on/off any of its options using different booleans as shown below:

```
<style name="Theme.CustomizedFullScreen" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in the menifest file, you just have to mention this style for your application as shown here:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomizedFullScreen"
```

You can also do same in Java file of the Activity right after onCreate() method as follows:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i tried to add in Java file of the Activity right after onCreate() method as follows: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); but don't function

Comment: Ok, so lets go into your problem step by step.  In the source code that you have posted, delete all lines of code after the following line:setContentView(R.layout.seconda); and run the application. Check if this layout is visible in full screen?

Comment: The background image is full screen, but incorrectly, and the table of edittex is located in the upper left. When the keyboard is also open divides the the screen with the image in the background . When i rotated the device breaks the layout  completely

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the theme of your application to full screen. Add the following to your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it will hide the notification bar also, you can view the full screen you will put this code in-between the super.onCreate() and SetContentView()

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_image_layout);
```

1. Fist line is used to remove the application name bar,
2. Second line used to remove the notification bar also.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still not familiar with programming in Android where in my code posted, I put these lines? Thanks

Comment: i edited my question, adding your lines of code but don't function. Why?

Comment: For your information, you must add this lines for all activities which you want full screen.

Comment: is what I did, however i have no errors or warnings in logcat, but the layout is not full screen and the matrix of edittext is not centered.

Comment: you mean, your edit-text is not properly aligned. am I correct?

Comment: this part of code that creates a tablelayout scrollable both horizontally and vertically,  and in this tablelayout there is a matrix of EditText. I want to view this layout, that contains also an image of background, full screen and the matrix of EditText centered on the screen

Comment: Now the background image fills the screen vertically and only the left side, the remaining part of the screen is black, the matrix of EditText is located in the upper left of the screen

Comment: if you don't mind tell me the full requirement as your need, i can post the code

Comment: I want to create a layout with an image of background, from Java, which is scrollable both horizontally and vertically to fill the screen, and display a matrix of EditText in the center of the layout created

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

tableRow = new TableRow(this); 
tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

for (int j = 0; j < 3  ; j++) {
values[i][j] = new EditText(this);
values[i][j].setHint("r: " + (i) + " " + "c: " + (j));
values[i][j].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
tableRow.addView(values[i][j]);
}

Comment: excuse my insistence, but I need your help